# How to scroll up in Emacs ansi-term

Tags: emacs

I've been Googling around and looking at Emacs built-in help but I have yet to determine how to scroll up (or down) in Emacs ansi-term.

I'm using Emacs 23.3.1, OS X, in iTerm2. Thanks!

Edit: I've noticed most the advice people give me doesn't work in ansi-term but does work in eshell. I have since moved to eshell.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In general, if you don't need full screen terminal emulation, `shell` or `eshell` are better choices.

However, if you decide to stick with `ansi-term`, press <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> to go into line mode.  Then you can move around normally with the usual cursor movement keys.  Press <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> to get back into char mode to interact with the terminal.

Alternatively, you can scroll backwards a screen at a time with <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> and just enter text to scroll back to the terminal input point.

Take a look at the [Emacs documentation on `term-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html#Terminal-emulator) (most of which applies equally to `ansi-term`) for more information.

Comment: I prefer ansi-term because more things are in color (like doing a git diff) then compared to other emacs terminal emulators. Doing a C-c C-j allowed me to then jump around up and down a page via the usual keys. Thanks!

Comment: I use shell with ansi color enabled, for the best of both worlds.  You can turn ansi color interpretation on for shell mode with this snippet in your .emacs: `(require 'ansi-color) (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)`

Answer (score 6):

Shift-page up/down (in Emacs-speak, `S-prior`/`S-next`) will work using the default bindings.

(While the normal `C-h m`/`C-h b` don't work to see mode information and bindings in this mode, you can still use `C-c M-x describe-mode`/`describe-bindings`, or depending on your setup, use <kbd>F1</kbd> or the <kbd>help</kbd> key instead of `C-h`.)

Comment: S-prior/S-next didn't work in ansi-term or eshell but thanks for the describe mode / bindings advice!

Comment: It's in the bindings; certainly worked for me. Maybe it has something to do with your terminal setup.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like most terminal apps I've seen map shift-page up/down to moving through the scrollback.  It definitely works if you run a GUI Emacs, which I'm surprised you don't if you're on the Mac... it integrates a lot better.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I use emacs in the terminal because I spend half my time ssh'd into a remote dev box and run emacs there. I'd use tramp but it's just not as fast as an ssh'd emacs. Especially at file access. Also having to switch up my meta key depending on emacs caused me annoyances, too. Do miss those extra colors though...

Comment: Yeah, I know the feeling and went through the same issue with TRAMP.  I either use NX to forward X11 Emacs or (more recently) just get dev environments running locally for everything, involving VMs if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

install evil-mode at first, press `C-z` to switch to vim key binding.

- You can use `C-f`, `C-b` to scroll up and down
- you can use `20%` to jump to to the top 20% of the buffer
- you can use `/`, `?`, `#`, `*` to search the text in the buffer.
- all the grep/filter commands now usable (occur, swiper, helm-swoop, .... just name a few)
- you can narrow/widen the buffer
- you can yank text

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: Page up, up arrow, Ctrl-V,Alt-V

Comment: Those don't work. I updated my question with OS and other details. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note that this works in eshell. I've now switched form using ansi-term to eshell.

Comment: I am using spacemacs with evil, so I needed to escape then hit shift + page up and page down.

Answer (score 1):

For ansi-term, I have this in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
          (function
           (lambda ()
             (define-key term-raw-map [?\C-c prior] 'scroll-down)
             (define-key term-raw-map [?\C-c next] 'scroll-up))))
```

Then I can use `C-c pgup` and `C-c pgdn` to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but with multi-term (zsh), and after reading the response from @muffinista (the `C-v` did not work for me) but  the `Alt-v` worked to go 1 page, after that you can use the normal `C-p` and `C-n` to scroll up and down.

This worked for me, but it depends a lot on which term you are using and key bindings you might have.

Answer (score -2):

Up and down are Ctrl-P and Ctrl-V.  There's a whole long list [here](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/emacs/)

Comment: Ctrl-P and Ctrl-V goes through the bash history. I updated my question with OS and other details. Thanks.

Comment: Also it's Ctrl-p and Ctrl-n. Ctrl-v will page down.